# Error on unrar in macOS

Tags: macos, rar

While running

```
unrar x <filename>
```

this error shows up,

```
ERROR: Unknown option: <filename>
```

Any solution(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use `<filename>` in the command?

The correct way to use the command is:
`unrar x archive`, where archive is the path to the archive file. For example `unrar x /home/user/archive.rar`.

Comment: it was for annotation only. But it worked fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error resolved.

I removed all the spaces among the `<filename>` of `<filename>.rar` and it worked.